# Is it OK to piggyback web services?

Tags: web-services, webservice-client

I am writing a client-server application where there is a small app on users' laptops in my company.

They need to read/write sql data (only a fairly small amount, essentially a query to see who last logged into something).

I don't want to expose my internal SQL server to "any" host on the internet, but have http access from a (trusted) internet web host. I am planning to write a web service on our internal IIS server which can be consumed by the external web host. Then I plan to have a second web service on the external host that is the target for the clients.

Essentially the workflow will be:

Client queries external host via webservice -> external host queries internal web server via web service

Is this over complex, or is it an accepted practice to avoid opening http/s traffic on my firewall from any host to the internal server?

Answer (score 0):

While this can work it is a little bit of over complication. Have one web service hosted and ask the network team to help you expose and secure the external facing side of it.

For example your server might have two network cards one for internal and one for external traffic. Also a DNS can route the external address to an internal IP address. The reason this is over complicating the issue  is that a change on the web service will require a change at two places. Also you now have two points in the chain that can break. The pattern you are implementing is called a facade and normally this is used to abstract details away actually come to think of it this is more the case of a proxy design pattern.

Another potential issue I see is that this type of service can be exploited by some of the more unsavory developers out there(HACKERS) to harvest user names. You mention nothing about how people will authorize against this service and from your description it sounds like this will be open for anyone to use. However this is just a hunch as you really have not provided enough information around this.